# Regex for this format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to use regex for this format to use in C#

format like this:

(EMPnnnRTLnnnn-aaaa or EMPnnnnBBCaaaa-nn) where n 
signifies a single number between (0 – 9) and “a” specifies a 
single lower-case alphabet between (A – Z).

e.g. 
EMP0001RTL1489-azio, EMP9212BBCgqui-02

Comment: I'm not sure what to say other than, "tough luck, write your own regex engine".  What you have *isn't* a regex.  To do what you're talking about you'd need to replace each 'n' with `\d` or `[0-9]`. You'd do a similar thing for the alphabet. Have you ever used Regex-es before?

Comment: @gdoron i have tried this Regex rx = new Regex("^[A-Z]{3}[o-9]{4}[A-Z]{3}[A-z]{3}[a-z0-9]{4}$"); but not working.

Comment: @swapnil, regexes are case-sensitive, so expressions like `[o-9]` or `[A-z]` are not going to do what you seem to think they do.

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"EMP(\d{3}RTL\d{4}-[a-z]{4})|\d{4}BBC[a-z]-\d{2}");
```

You should really learn to use your tools, @swapnil - clipboard development isn't a good habit and bad for your soul.

Comment: It isn't a good habit, but it works - someone always gives an answer to these lazy people. +1 though.